# how to make a sliding drawer not transparent?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

on my mapview there is a sliding drawer. When the drawer is open, I can still touch and slide the map via it. I changed the background color of the drawer, but only the color is changed, it is still "transparent".
Can someone teach how to "fix" it? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By giving background color to its contents

```
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should only need to make the drawer [focusable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afocusable) in order for it to take taps from the map view in the background (even if those taps have no actions associated with them).

Comment: no the focusable doesn't work, the sliding drawer is still "transparent"

Answer (score 0):

try this library for sliding drawer https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

Comment: thanks for the reply.But I want my sliding drawer slides from down to top.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the content of the sliding drawer with a LinearLayout with a background.
here is an xml that will solve your problem :

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/friends_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" 
    android:focusable="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pull_me" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:background="#fff">
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/friends_lv" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```